# Optimizing query for finding friends

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which represents relations between pairs of people.

```
user_relating | user_related | relation_type 
--------------------------------------------
     1        |       2      |      1      --> means user 1 follows user 2
```

I need to find all friends for a specific user X. 
Friendship means that two people follow each other.
So if user A follows users B, C. And users B, C follow A, then B, C are friends of A.

I've written this query :

```
SELECT users.* -- user's followers
FROM users
JOIN user_relations rel
ON users.id = rel.user_relating AND user_related = 2

INTERSECT

SELECT users.* -- who the user follows
FROM users
JOIN user_relations rel
ON users.id = rel.user_related AND user_relating = 2;
```

But I think it's inefficient. 
Is there a more optimized way to get this done?

I've tried doing something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.*
FROM users f
JOIN user_relations u1 
    on f.id = u1.user_related
JOIN user_relations u2 
    on f.id = u2.user_relating

WHERE u1.user_related = 2 
   or u2.user_related = 2;
```

it seems much more efficient judging by the EXPLAIN ANALYZE (though I only have a really small table, like 10 rows so I'm not sure it's a good measurement).

But the problem here is that it returns the user in question too. Meaning, if I want friends of User B , then this query returns User B together with all his friends. Can I somehow exclude User B from the query result?

And, as stated formerly, I would be glad to receive some ideas for the most optimized and efficient way to do this kind of queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most efficient method is:

```
select ur.*
from user_relations ur
where ur.user_relating < ur.user_related and
      ur.relation_type = 1 and
      exists (select 1
              from user_relations ur2
              where ur2.user_relating = ur.user_related and
                    ur2.user_related = ur.user_relating and
                    ur2.relation_type = 1
             );
```

And for performance, you want an index on `user_relations(user_relating, user_related, relationship_type)`.

That said, this is similar to your version with the `join`, but does not require removing duplicates.

If you have lots of different relationship types, then an index on that column could also help.

EDIT:

If you have a particular user and want their friends:

```
select (case when user_relating = 2 then user_related else user_relating end) as user_friend
from user_relations ur
where ur.user_relating < ur.user_related and
      ur.relation_type = 1 and
      exists (select 1
              from user_relations ur2
              where ur2.user_relating = ur.user_related and
                    ur2.user_related = ur.user_relating and
                    ur2.relation_type = 1
             ) and
      2 in (ur.user_relating, user_related)
```

Comment: thank you! I see it doesn't retrieve the users from `users` table like in my queries, and I also didn't quite understand how to ask here for friends of a specific user, for example for friends of `user_id = 2`. Could you please update how I can return the users with this solution instead of relations? 
regarding my relations table, I have only two types of relationship at this point (follow, block), though that might change in the future.
Regarding indexes, I have two indexes , one `relating_user, relation_type` and `related_user, relation_type`. And the PK is `relating_user, related_user`.

Comment: am I fine with those indexes I mentioned? or do I have to make the index as you suggested (one index covering the 3 columns)

Comment: With your primary key, no additional index is needed for this query.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, it seems in fact what I needed and appears more efficient. Just one thing, if you don't mind please - what I meant regarding getting the users as a result of the query, is getting the relevant users records from `Users` table, not just the user ids.  For that, do I simply need to "wrap" you query and then call `select * from users where id = <your query>` ?

Comment: @bvtp . . . It is probably simplest to use the answer as a subquery or CTE and then `join` to the `users` table.  The `join` key is not obvious, because it could be either column.  If you `join` *before* the `case`, the code will be much more complicated.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I did it like this :
`select * from users JOIN (<your answer>) friends ON users.id = friends.user_friend` . Is that what you meant? hopefully that additional join won't detract from the performance much

Comment: @BVtp . . . Exactly.